# RDLC autofill body of report

Tags: visual-studio-2013, report, rdlc, autofill

I have a problem with `RDLC` report that I can not solve.
I have a `Tablix` with inside the data to display in the report.

The data within it are a list of products with the relative sizes, which are dynamic and vary from product to product. 
So some products may have more or less sizes

This is my `Tablix`:

[image: Report Designer]

In this case, the product has many cuts and then the table is extended and reaches almost half report:

[image: Long]

In this rather sizes are few and then only arrive at the beginning of the report:

[image: Short]

How can I make sure that the table is properly sized and arrive always until the end of report?

This is the full report:

[image: Report]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try something like:

1. Add empty columns to the `Tablix` so you can reach the end of the page
2. Set columns order visibility so that you have a fixed number of columns (20 columns max = 3 Columns with data + 17 without data for example)

Every columns should have a condition based on his number :

Column 1 condition:

```
=iif(YourMaxNumberOfColumnsWithData.Value > 1,true,false)
```

Column 2 condition:

```
=iif(YourMaxNumberOfColumnsWithData.Value > 2,true,false)
```

Column 3 condition:

```
=iif(YourMaxNumberOfColumnsWithData.Value > 3,true,false)
```

and so on...

Comment: L'ho implementata nel programma.
Subito sembrava una soluzione perfetta per il mio caso ma a distanza di mesi ci siamo accorti che in realtà è una vera e propria merda.
E' proprio UNTA E BISUNTA.

MA ENAC OID ED MA ENAC OID ED....I CRYYY WHEN KIWI WASH THE HAAAAAAAAAAAAAIR HAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIR HAAAAAAAAAIR